# Customize failure handling in FluentAssertions

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I'm trying to use FluentAssertions not only as testing assertions framework but also to check runtime contracts (like advanced Debug.Assert, and I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49724379/should-fluentassertions-be-used-in-production-code) question).
The desired behaviour is:

- In debug mode: throw exceptions (it does).
- In release mode: do not stop method execution (no exception is thrown) but execute custom action (write to log).

Is there a way to customize failure handling behaviour? There is `IAssertionStrategy` interface which is exactly about failure handling. However, it's implementations are hard-coded inside the AssertionScope.
Did I miss something in the sources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `FluentAssertions.Common.Services.ThrowException` to override the behavior. Note though it was never designed for that.

Comment: Didn't notice it's a delegate, not a method, thanks.